# Where developers save choice options in Django?

Tags: python, django, multiplechoicefield

For example i have a choice

```
COLORS = (
    ('red', 'Red'),
    ('blue', 'Blue'),
    ('yellow', 'Yellow'),
)
```

Should i create a model like:

```
class Color(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(...)
```

and create some color instances in django-admin or i need to declare CHOICE(above), where i save all colors(even if there are many colors)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you need to make a model `product` and this model has multiple colors. In this case you need to create a model for `color`.

In case every `product` has one color you can use `choice`.

Comment: But is it a right way to create a list of colors if i have for example 30 colors or even more and i'll filter by colors these products later?

Comment: No, you don't have to do that, if you have a lot of colors just create model for them.